# Unable to access an error message corresponding to your field name

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a callback function that check_captcha which sees if `$row` is `==0` or `== 1` (this information is queried from sql).

The problem is that I can not call it from `$self->form_validation->set_rule('captcha', 'call_back_check_captcha')` due to the fact that my function takes in a `$row` var. The way I'm calling it now I get a Unable to access error message. How can I make this work?

```
function check_captcha( $row)
{
    if($row ==0)//didnt find any
    {
        $this->form_validation->set_message('captcha', 'text dont match captcha');
        return FALSE;
    }
    else
    {
        return TRUE;
    }
}


function create_member() 
        {   

            $past = time() - 7200; 

        $this->db->query("DELETE FROM captcha WHERE captcha_time <".$past);                 
        $sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS count FROM captcha WHERE word =? AND ip_address =?";     
        $binds = array($_POST['captcha'], $this->input->ip_address(), $past);
        $query= $this->db->query($sql, $binds);

        $row = $query->row(); //row query rows : if it found an entry =1 

            $self->check_captcha($row->count);

        //VALIDATIONS
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('first_name', 'First Name', 'trim|required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('last_name', 'Last Name', 'trim|required');      
        $this->form_validation->set_rules( 'email_address', 'Email Address', 'trim|required|valid_email|unique[user.email_address]');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'Username', 'trim|required|min_length[4]|unique[user.username]');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'trim|required|min_length[4]|max_leng[32]');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('password2', 'Password Confirmation','trim|required|matches[password]');
        if(!$_POST['captcha']){
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('captcha', 'Captcha','trim|required');}else{
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('captcha', 'Captcha', 'callback_check_captcha');}

        if($this->form_validation->run()==FALSE)
        {   //this -> to the curr obj(UserController) && registraion() points to the the function in controller
            $this->registration();  //reloads reg page so they can fill out right stuff
        }
        else
```

Comment: you shoul add a `_` in front of function name , so that i could not be called from url. `check_captcha` should be  `_check_captcha`

Answer (score 52, accepted):

```
$this->form_validation->set_message('check_captcha', 'text dont match captcha');
```

The message name corresponds to the **function**, not the **field**. So setting it to "**check_captcha**" will fix your bug. The error message will use the correct field name.

Comment: did the same mistake thnx

Comment: It confused me, you are using `set_message()` here but the question starter uses `set_rules()`. Is this a typo by you? Btw, I also use `set_rules()` and have same message.

Comment: I used the function name instead of the field name but it still shows the same error message.. I already have a separate language file containing error messages so I'd prefer not to add more lines in the form_validation_lang file to avoid discrepancies in the future. what should I do now?

Answer (score 11):

Actually the best way, instead of write the error message directly on controller, would be add this entry "check_captcha" on languages.

In my case, the message for validation rule (form validation) "less_than" was not present.

I changed the file **/system/language/??/form_validation_lang.php**. I've added the missing entry.

Comment: Yes. I also fixed this message by adding missing language text.

Answer (score 2):

That helped me

go to application/config/autoload.php and add "Security" helper class there.

```
$autoload['helper'] = array('security');
```

Or add this before your form validation

```
$this->load->helper('security');
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set **error message** in `set_rules` :

`$this->form_validation->set_rules('captcha', 'Captcha', 'callback_check_captcha',`

`array('check_captcha' => 'text dont match captcha'));`

Answer (score 0):

add a entry to your language file with named of the part inside the (yourfieldname) of the errormessage - thats solved the problem

Answer (score 0):

Even if the question is already answered, there is another error that can lead to the same error message:

If you call your callback **checkCaptcha**, it will not work. Prefer always a name like **check_captcha** as recommended in Codeigniter/General Topics/PHP style guide.